# `rbenv exec` の仕様(挙動)は?

Tags: ruby, rbenv

[`capistrano-rbenv`](https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv) のリポジトリを見ていました。

そこで、この gem は `rbenv exec` によって、 rails のコマンドを実行することを想定しているようだ、と思っています。

一方、この `rbenv exec` のコマンドは、[rbenv の公式 github の README](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) を読んでいても、その挙動についての説明が記述されていないな、と思っています。

## 質問

- `rbenv exec commands...` を実行したときに、これはどのような動作を行なうコマンドなのでしょうか?

Comment: ドキュメントに載ってない理由は　https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/1182　が参考になりそうな気がします

Comment: 仕組みについては https://stackoverflow.com/a/9422296/1979953 が詳しそうです

Answer (score 0):

"rbenv exec とは" で検索しただけですが、以下のような記述をしているページを見つけました。

**参考:**
[rbenvおよびbundlerの基本的な使用方法](https://www.qoosky.io/techs/8a0f1d8d9e)

> ややこしいですが、bundleコマンドはgemコマンドでインストールします。"rbenv exec" は「システムrubyのgem」ではなく「rbenvで現在有効なrubyのgem」であることを明記する表記です。"gem" がrbenvで有効なrubyのgemを指している場合は省略可能ではあります。
>
> ```
> $ rbenv exec gem install bundler
> $ rbenv rehash
> ```